# Show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{4^n}\sin (nz)$ comveges pointwise

Tags: complex-analysis

Condiser $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{4^n}\sin (nz)$$ in the region $|z|\leq1$.

Show that $f_n$ converges uniformly and decide whether it converges uniformly.

Well, I think that I should start with $|f_n(z)|=|\dfrac{1}{4^n}\sin (nz)|$ and I don't know how to work it out.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the fact that $\sin nz = \frac{e^{nz}-e^{-nz}}{2i}$ to bound the (modulus of the) numerator in the region $\lvert z\rvert \leq 1$, e.g. by $c^{n}$ for some $c\in[0,4)$; and then consider a comparison test with the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{c^n}{4^n}$.